# Angular directive $http. Before and after http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple things..

```
<my-directive info-key="total_users"></my-directive>
```

Result: `<div>You asked for {{ infoKey }}, you get {{ apiValue }}</div>`

Now the thing is that before the API respond I want to add some html there.

E.g. `<div You asked for {{ infoKey }}, you get <small>pending..</small></div>`
and then remove it for the API result.

Of course I tried to initialise the result `$scope.apiValue = 'pending...';` but I was just wondering if there is a better way because I'm not so familiar with "the Angular way" yet.

I even though that maybe my whole logic is false so please check the code snippet below.

```js
apiUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow';

angular.module('app', []).directive('myDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>you asked for <strong>{{ infoKey }}</strong>, you get: <strong>{{ apiValue }}</strong></div>',
      controller: ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.askApi = function(key) {
            $http.get(apiUrl).success(function(data) {
              $scope.apiValue = data.items[0][key];
            });
          };
        }
      ],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.infoKey = attrs.infoKey;
        scope.askApi(scope.infoKey);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head></head>

<body>
  <my-directive info-key="total_users"></my-directive>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it is very OK. My perception of "the Angular way" is to use the model to control the view, which is exactly what you are doing. An idea: The directive could manage a boolean `$scope.pending` variable; the template could utilize it to alter the class of the `{{ apiValue }}` container (e.g. show an inline spinner or even display the `pedning...` message using CSS, so that you don't have to dirty the model).

Comment: Or you can use a filter such as `default` to setup some default value.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I tried something according your "pending boolean" idea. http://jsfiddle.net/zv2uko8z/ . I like it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generally on the right track. However, as you've noticed you don't follow the best angular practices. A few things that I would change (shown below):

1. Avoid using $scope and instead use controllerAs syntax. Avoiding $scope gets rid of a whole lot of errors and confusion that can happen due to the prototypical inheritance and sharing that $scopes have.
2. Don't use replace, instead use the  element as your containing element. It is functionally equivalent and makes your markup more semantic. The only thing to bare in mind here is that custom elements will have a display: inline; style by default rather than display: block; that it would have if it was a div.
3. Use bindToController. To be fair this came in with angular 1.3 and your example used angular 1.2. Suffice to say it removes some of the code.
4. Separate your API access logic into a service.

And here are another few things I would add that I haven't shown:

1. Tests! Angular is set up to make unittesting easy. Your understanding of the code will improve massively by writing tests, not to mention the other benefits you get from writing them.
2. Handle errors. After the .success() of the promise in the controller you should have a .catch() block and handle an error. Even just presenting an error to the user would be of benefit, or even including a retry button.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('myDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'you asked for <strong>{{ vm.infoKey }}</strong>, you get: <strong>{{ vm.apiValue }}</strong>',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {
        infoKey: '@'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      controller: ['stackoverflowInfo',
        function(stackoverflowInfo) {
          var vm = this;

          vm.apiValue = 'pending ...';

          stackoverflowInfo.get(vm.infoKey).then(function(value) {
            vm.apiValue = value;
          });
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]).service('stackoverflowInfo', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
  var svc = this;
  var apiUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow';

  svc.get = get;
  
  function get (key) {
    return getFromApi().then(function(data) {
      return data.items[0][key];
    });
  }

  function getFromApi () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get(apiUrl).success(defer.resolve).error(defer.reject);
    return defer.promise;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head></head>

<body>
  <my-directive info-key="total_users"></my-directive>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great analysis! Thank you for your time (Y)